# How to hide password from ps command?

Tags: linux

I have below script as:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

. /filelocation/propertyfile.properties                    #key value pairs are stored here(KEY,PASSWORD,etc being used below)

# Executing java proc
exec java -Dproc.name='(java instance)' -DAPP_NAME="name of instance" -somearguements -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=$KEY -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=$PASSWORD -Xms512m -Xmx1024m MainClass
```

After running the above script, I can see the process running using the ps command.
But I also see the argument values key and passwords visible.

Can you please help me how can I hide those values?

Answer (score 1):

No way!

**Do not put passwords in command line arguments and environment variables.**

Read the password from a file descriptor in the same ways as GPG does it:
[How to use Gnupg's passphrase-fd argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895122/how-to-use-gnupgs-passphrase-fd-argument)